# Ultra simple iPhone App Doesnt Display a Label - why?

Tags: iphone

I have just done a tutorial for a Hello World iPhone App.

It doesn't work :-(

Here's what I did:

- Create a view based application called HelloWorld
- Drag a Label onto HelloWorldViewConroiller.xib that says "Hello World"
- Click Build and Run

According to the book I am reading, I should see the label's text on screen.
Instead I see a gray screen with nothing.

What am I missing?

Note: I tried this using a Window based application and that didn't work either - blank screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What an idiot - you need to save the View first. Pressing Build and Run does not actually save the View. I am coming from a Visual Studio environment where such things don't happen.

Comment: If you upgrade to XCode4 you will not have this issue as IB is integrated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi
Build and run will only use saved files to guild and display your programe. However IB (the program in which you drag and connect your label) is/was separate from XCode and it gets confused about what is and what isn't saved already.

-make sure to save your interface in IB before you run
-make sure that your label has text in it
-make sure you are editing the write file (close IB and open your .xib file again)

do not worry, everybody was there at some point